# How is it possible for a vector to be expressed with the same expression as its projection into another vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, numerical-linear-algebra, orthogonality

I am a little confused with the following theorems (and resulting expressions):

1. If S={**v**<sub>1</sub>, **v**<sub>2</sub>, ...,**v**<sub>n</sub>} is an orthonormal basis for an inner product space V, and if **u** is any vector in V, then

> **u** = (**u**, **v<sub>1</sub>**)**v**<sub>1</sub> + (**u**, **v**<sub>2</sub>)**v**<sub>2</sub> + ... + (**u**, **v**<sub>n</sub>)**v**<sub>n</sub>

2. If W is a finite-dimensional subspace of an inner product space V, and {**v**<sub>1</sub>, **v**<sub>2</sub>, ...,**v**<sub>n</sub>} is an orthonormal basis for W, and **u** is any vector in V, then

> proj<sub>W</sub>**u** = (**u**, **v<sub>1</sub>**)**v**<sub>1</sub> +
>   (**u**, **v**<sub>2</sub>)**v**<sub>2</sub> + ... + (**u**,
>   **v**<sub>n</sub>)**v**<sub>n</sub>

(explanation of this dervition, if needed, is given below)*

---

What confuses me, is that both expressions are the same, and it seems to me that both the vector **u**, and its projection on **w**<sub>1</sub> is the same. How does this make sense? How can a vector and its projection be expressed by the same expression?

I'd appreciate any help/comment/explanation regarding this.

---

*The expression in 2 is dervied as follows: vector **u** is expressed as the sum of two orthogonal vectors **w**<sub>1</sub> and **w**<sub>2</sub>. Vector **w**<sub>1</sub> is then decomposed according to theorem 1 above, and because **w**<sub>2</sub> is orthogonal to W, it follows that (**w**<sub>2</sub>, **v**<sub>1</sub>) = (**w**<sub>2</sub>, **v**<sub>2</sub>) = ... = (**w**<sub>2</sub>, **v**<sub>n</sub>) = 0, allowing us to rewrite every (**w**<sub>1</sub>, **v**<sub>i</sub>) in the expression as (**w**<sub>1</sub> + **w**<sub>2</sub>, **v**<sub>i</sub>) = (**u**, **v**<sub>i</sub>), for **i=1, 2, ..., n**.

Comment: The $\mathbf v$s are different in the two formulas, but it’s not coincidental that the formulas look the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say we have a finite dimensional inner product space $V$ and a subspace $W \subseteq V$ and let $\mathbf{u} \in V$. If we want to apply the first statement, we need some orthonormal basis $\mathbf{v}_1, \dots, \mathbf{v}_n$ of $V$ and then we get

$$ \mathbf{u} = \sum_{i=1}^n (\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}_i) \mathbf{v}_i. $$

If we want to apply the second statement, we need an **orthonormal basis of $W$**, not of $V$! Let us choose such a basis $\mathbf{w}_1,\dots,\mathbf{w}_m$ (with $m \leq n$). Then

$$ \operatorname{proj}_W(\mathbf{u}) = \sum_{i=1}^m (\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{w}_i) \mathbf{w}_i $$

so you can see that the expressions are different. Actually, you can always choose an orthonormal basis $\mathbf{v}_1,\dots,\mathbf{v}_n$ of $V$ such that the first $m$ vectors $\mathbf{v}_1,\dots,\mathbf{v}_m$ form an orthonormal basis of $W$ and then you get the equations

$$ \mathbf{u} = \sum_{i=1}^n (\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}_i) \mathbf{v}_i,\\
\operatorname{proj}_W(\mathbf{u}) = \sum_{i=1}^m (\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}_i) \mathbf{v}_i $$

but they are still different because the summation in the first goes up to $n$ while the summation in the second goes up to $m$. If $m = n$ then $V = W$ and indeed $\operatorname{proj}_W(\mathbf{u}) = \mathbf{u}$ but if not, you get different expressions.

Comment: This was a great explanation! I feel kinda stupid now, but still glad I posted the question because your answer clarifies a lot of things for me. Thank you!

Comment: @BesianS: It's ok, you're welcome! Actually, pedagogically it would be better to change the names and the indices of the vectors in the second statement so that it wouldn't cause confusion but there's also a reason for keeping the same names and indices - this suggests that the second theorem is just a corollary of the first and this is indeed the case because it is obtained form the first theorem by taking $W = V$ and $\operatorname{proj}_W(\mathbf{u})$ instead of $\mathbf{u}$.